# x86 Assembly Passing Parameters by Reference

Tags: assembly, x86, pass-by-reference

Below is my code for assembly language. I can pass by a stack parameter value using "push [edi]" but I cannot seem to pass by reference using "push OFFSET [edi]". What's the correct syntax to pass something by reference in this case?

```
sortList        PROC
;Parameter memory addresses:
;numbers    @ [ebp+8]
;list       @ [ebp+12]

;Used to access stack parameters
push        ebp
mov         ebp, esp

;Sets up the array
mov         edi, [ebp+12]               ;Puts in the address of the list array
mov         ecx, [ebp+8]                ;Sets up the loop counter for the array

;Testing swapNumber function
push        [edi]                           ;array 1 pushed will be ebp+12
add         edi, 4
push        [edi]                           ;array 2 pushed will be ebp+8
call        swapNumber

pop         ebp
ret         8
sortList        ENDP
```

Comment: Push the pointer not the memory operand.  i.e. ``push edi`` instead of ``push [edi]``

Comment: Oh wow... it was a simple fix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That isn't "by reference", it doesn't let the callee modify the caller's register.  It's just passing the pointer value, without dereferencing.  Like in C passing `foo(ptr)` instead of `foo(*ptr)`.  The pointer is still a reference to whatever it was pointing at, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
mov edi,8 ; edi = 8
push edi ; we push to the stack the value '8'
push [edi]; we push to the stack the value in the address memory:8
;in your case i'm pretty sure that you mean push edi instead of push [edi]
```

Answer (score 0):

the index register `edi` holds a pointer to your data. `[edi]` dereferences this pointer (similar to C's `*` operator). So, if `push [edi]` pushes the data pointed to by `edi` onto the stack, to push the `edi` itself onto the stack, you need to... `push edi` =).