# How to return void in y86

Tags: assembly, x86, y86

I am trying to write the following function in y86 (Assembly)

C code:

```
void f (long x, long y, long *sum, long *diff) {
    *sum = x + y;
}
long a, b;
void main (void)
{
    f (7, 10, &a, &b);
    halt();
}
```

Don't give me the answer to how to write this in assembly, I only want the answer to both my question :

Question 1 : How do we pass a reference as a parameter?

Question 2 : How do we return a void value?

Side-notes:

I've looked up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786154/x86-assembly-passing-parameters-by-reference), but the answer `push [edi];` doesn't work for y86.

Normally, in a function with a return value, we use: `ret` in order to return what's in the `%eax` register, and to remove the return adress in the stack. Now I just want to remove the return address without actually returning a value. 
According to [this website](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html),

> If your function returns void (e.g. no value), the contents of these registers are not used.

Is it possible that the value is returned but we just don't use it, or am I understanding it wrong? I'd like more explanation on this if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by a "void value"? Do you mean a void pointer? The C function `void f()` does not return a value. Conversely, `main()` does, so it should be defined as `int main(void)`

Comment: "Is it possible that the value is returned but we just don't use it" well you can't have *no value* in a register, so if the function is of type void, `eax` is ignored by the caller, since its meaning is undefined.

Comment: The RET instruction doesn't return a value in the EAX register, it **only** pops the returns address off the stack and jumps to that address. It's only by convention that EAX is used as return value. It's up to the calling function and called function to follow the convention and use EAX for the return value, *if any*.

Comment: Yes, assembly language has no concept of "returning" values. The called subroutine may store values in number of locations, and the calling subroutine just retrieves them from those locations before something else overwrites them.